# Execute Python through PHP via Crontab

Tags: php, python, linux, cron

I've got a cronjob running for a PHP script which makes a shell_exec call to a python script passing an argument which is then acted on in Python. This all works fine when run from the command line, however when I try and run it as a cronjob, it logs the output of the PHP fine, but doesn't seem to be executing the python script.

My cron:

`* * * * *  /usr/bin/php /home/pi/php/random_article.php >> /home/pi/php/logs/random_art_log.txt`

My PHP:

```php
$twitter = "Food for thought...: " . $random_link . " - $link";
echo "Twitter string: $twitter\n";
$output = shell_exec('python post_article_twitter.py \'' . $twitter . '\'');
echo $output;
```

My Python:

```python
api = Twython (CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)


'''HOW TO POST'''
#This posts a status as the first system argument passed to it
api.update_status(status=sys.argv[1])
```

I know there may be an easier way of posting to twitter than all this, but the python script is used by a lot of other scripts I use so I'd rather not rebuild it in PHP.

Any help in getting it to work via a cronjob would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: try full path to python interpreter on shell exec?

Comment: Why don't you just execute the python script directly from crontab? Or if you need a script that builds the message, write that script in python as well and just import your other python script?